# AmCharts: How to dynamically update the balloon according to legend changes?

Tags: javascript, html, graph, charts, amcharts

I have another question regarding AmCharts. I have got numerous graphs, but want to show only one Balloon. I am using the

> chartCursor.oneBalloonOnly

right now. I am also using AmLegend. I want to dynamically change the information within the one balloon whenever the user dismisses or adds a graph via legend.

I imagine if kind of like this:

```
            function adjustBalloonText(graphDataItem, graph){
            var date = ""; //some kind of getDateInScrollbar here
            var distance = ""; // some kind of getGraph1Value here
            var duration = ""; // some kind of getGraph2Value here as well
            return "date <br> distance <br> duration";
        }
```

Please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey. This is not how StackOverflow works. If you want support, reach out directly to amCharts at contact@amcharts.com. SO is for helping you solve issues, not solving them for you.

Comment: I have already reached out to the amCharts support. I am indeed new to SO. Thanks for the reminder.